# Is the runtime of checking for duplicate primary keys in SQL Server O(n)?

Tags: sql-server

I was curious and I couldn't find too much info on this. Is it also O(n) for checking for duplicates among primary keys?

Is it the same for most other SQL databases?

Is there a place that lists this info?

Comment: Primary keys can't be duplicate...

Comment: Complexity notation like `O(n)` is meaningless unless you define what variable you're representing by `n`, and what operation you're performing. As written, your question is too vague to beanswerable.

Comment: @Juru And what is the algorithm that ensures this is true when you try to put in a duplicate key? And what is the complexity of that algorithm? Your comment suggests you might feel this isn't a legitimate question, but it is.. it's about what the database is doing when checking the duplicate-based legality of a candidate key entry.

Comment: @IMSoP It's pretty clear from context what `n` refers to in this case. Given the useful answers, I disagree with your claim that it's too vague to be answerable.

Comment: @EMS I misread the question. I thought the goal was to find the complexity of executing a query like SELECT DISTINCT PK FROM TABLE. Which would be a pointless thing to do. My mistake.

Comment: @EMS Prior to edits (not by the OP, but others interpreting their intent) it was possible to read the question as "are queries O(n), for example finding duplicates". The interpretation taken appears to have been correct, though, so I guess everyone's a winner. :)

Comment: @IMSoP: Yup, I edited the title, because "what is the complexity of an arbitrary query" is so broad as to essentially be unanswerable ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A primary key in SQL Server is always backed by an index (in fact, a B-tree for non-Hekaton tables). An index allows for `O(log N)` lookup (and duplicate checking).

In practice it's hard to measure the difference to `O(1)` behavior even if you aim at it. The upper index levels tend to be cached and the tree is very flat. The maximum tree level in SQL Server is 15 levels (you need to load the index pages with ~900 byte keys for that to force minimum fanout).

Each index row must be 807 bytes in size to fit at most 9 of them on a page. Then, the index size on level L is `807*9^L`. L starts at 1. `L == 15 => 807*9^15/10^12 = 166154 TB`. [Maximum database size: 524,272 TB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx). So the maximum level is 15.

Comment: It's worthwhile to note that in many cases, the relevant data structure is a B-Tree, or some optimized variant, for persisting the index, in case the OP wants to verify if that is true about a given database's index implementation or just look up more about it.

Comment: This pretty much answers my question, thanks!

Comment: "*In practice it is O(1) because the upper index levels tend to be cached*" - the caching doesn't change the complexity. That will still be O(log N). The operations involved are faster, but it still requires the same *number* of operations.

Comment: It is only "effectively `O(1)`" with respect to IO operations that result from the activity, not the actual index navigation algorithm, because with a table that sees regular use you are unlikely to see more than a page or two read from disk when comparing one value against the primary key. You shouldn't bank on the ideal case though. Considering just the algorithm and not storage structures, searching for a value a structure with a balanced index is an `O(log N)` operation.

Comment: Is there really a maximum tree level? If I push a gazillion of rows into a table, why can't I have an index with 9 levels?

Comment: Because of the maximum database size. I once calculated what the max tree level would be at minimum fan-out. I think the number was 8. This is not explicitly documented.

Comment: Each index row must be 807 byte to fit at most 9 of them on a page. Then, the index size on level L is `807*9^L`. L starts at 1. `L = 15 => 807*9^15/10^12 = 166154 TB`. Max. database size: 524,272 TB. So the maximum level is 15. I remembered a wrong number.

Answer (score 0):

Since primary key is unique, I assume your question is about the complexity how the database system determines whether a key is a duplicate, then it is not O(n), and it is practically O(1).

Comment: I can claim that all algorithms are "practically" O(1). O(n) notation is about what happens on the limit (to infinity), not about practicality.